# IF THEN clause in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures

I'm a newbie with this and I do not understand why I'm getting an error when I execute this stored procedure.

Can anyone help me out!?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_UserPassword]
    (@username nvarchar(50),
     @password nvarchar(20))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @flag bit
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @flag = (SELECT firstloginflag 
                 FROM USER
                 WHERE username = @username)

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    IF(@flag = 0)
        UPDATE USER 
        SET firstloginflag = 1, password = @password
        WHERE username = @username
    ELSE
        UPDATE USER 
        SET password = @password
        WHERE username = @username
END
```

This is the error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 6, Procedure Update_UserPassword, Line 31
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.Update_UserPassword'.

Comment: You may have created this procedure in a different schema.  It's probably not in `dbo`

Comment: Not sure why you've fixated on `IF`/`THEN` in your tagging and question title, since it doesn't seem to be in any way related

Comment: You should ask this on http://dba.stackexchange.com/. SO is for **programming questions only**

Answer (score 1):

There is no existing `Update_UserPassword` stored procedure in the current database and/or schema.

You are either in the wrong data base and need to execute a `use [database name];`, using the wrong schema meaning you need to prepend the schema name - `[schema].Update_UserPassword` , or change the `ALTER PROCEDURE` to a `CREATE PROCEDURE`.